# Remove the last character of each row in a text file

Tags: python, filesystems

I have a text file that I need to read and perform an FFT onto.

Basically, the file reads something like this:

```
1458 1499 1232 1232 1888 ... 2022-09-11 09:32:51.076
1459 1323 1999 1323 1823 ... 2022-09-11 09:32:51.199
```

and so on. Each row has 200 columns, and I want to basically read each row, up to each column while ignoring the last column that has the time.

So far I've tried this:

```py
with open('file') as f:
    w, h = [int(x) for x in next(f).split()] # read first line
    array = []
    for line in f: # read rest of lines
        array.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])
```

But I don't know how to remove the last characters.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
array = []
with open('file.txt','r') as tf:
  for lines in tf.readlines():
    array.append(' '.join(lines.split()[:-2]))

print(array)
```

If you want to append the list of integers from each of the lines:

```
array = []
with open('file.txt','r') as tf:
  for lines in tf.readlines():
    array.append([int(x) for x in lines.split()[:-2]])

print(array)
```

Comment: or `array.append(line.rsplit(' ', 1)[0])` might be an option

Comment: Would need to use: `array.append(lines.rsplit(' ', 2)[0])` - for this example

Answer (score 5):

Just a little modification on the last line.

[:-2] means all columns except the last two.
I guess it's -2 instead of -1 because if you want to omit the datetime you have to omit the date part and the time part (which have been splitted because of the space character), e.g "2022-09-11 09:32:51.076"

```py
with open('file') as f:
    w, h = [int(x) for x in next(f).split()] # read first line
    array = []
    for line in f: # read rest of lines
        array.append([int(x) for x in line.split()[:-2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to solve this. One way is to read each line as a listand then take all but the last item:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a[:-1]
print b
```

then use the resulting list b

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all previous answers, many ways to solve this. This seems to do the trick for my test-file:

```
array = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        w = [x for x in line.split()] # read first line
        array.append(w[:-1])
```